# Regarding Phase Angle Of a Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier

Please tell me what would be the phase angle diagram of Fourier transform

$$X(e^{jw})=\frac{1}{1-ae^{-jw}}$$

and how?

Comment: In general, on this site people want to see you put some effort into your homework and show you work to date.  An important component of learning is doing.

Comment: I edited the formula for clarity, but I found a typo in the parenthesis positioning in your initial question. Please check that the new formatting reflects what you are asking.

Comment: The question is ontopic, please don't hold/delete/migrate it. Fourier-transformation is one of the most important mathematical tools for planning/handling linear or linearisable electronic systems.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compute the phase of the denominator and add a minus sign because for any complex number \$z\$ you have

$$\arg\left\{\frac{1}{z}\right\}=-\arg\{z\}$$

where \$\arg\{\}\$ is the argument (or phase) of a complex number. So in your case

$$z=1-ae^{-jw}=1-a(\cos w-j\sin w)=1-a\cos w+ja\sin w$$

So the phase of \$X(e^{j w})\$ is

$$\phi_X(w)=-\arctan\left(\frac{a\sin w}{1-a\cos w}\right)\pm\pi$$

where the possible addition (or subtraction) of \$\pi\$ is determined by the signs of the numerator and the denominator inside the \$\arctan()\$ function. In many programming languages the computation of the correct phase value is implemented as '[atan2()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2)', so you don't need to worry about adding or subtracting \$\pi\$ after evaluating the \$\arctan()\$ function.

Comment: @user43213: You're welcome! If you're happy with it you can accept this answer by hitting the check mark next to it.